Puppeteer Fails to Scrape Site with SSL Issue on Server (Works Locally)
I'm trying to scrape a site using Puppeteer, and while everything works fine on my local machine, I encounter SSL-related issues when I try to run the script on my server. I’ve tried several suggested solutions but haven’t found one that resolves the issue.
Here's what I’ve done so far:
Downgraded Puppeteer to various older versions, as well as tried the latest version.
Tested Node versions: I’m currently using Node v20.17 and Puppeteer v23.3.0.
Verified the issue using curl -v , which shows the connection stalls after resolving the host but times out while connecting.
Here’s the curl output:
* Host registration.ec.ap.gov.in:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 103.129.75.144
* Trying 103.129.75.144:443...
* Failed to connect to registration.ec.ap.gov.in port 443: Connection timed out

I've tried all the typical fixes for SSL issues, such as ignoring certificate errors in Puppeteer and experimenting with different Puppeteer and Node.js versions. However, the issue persists only on the server.
Does anyone know how to resolve or work around SSL-related issues specifically for Puppeteer on a server, or could you suggest any alternative solutions?

The page or url does not load from my country as well, maybe it's country restricted?

check from browser it will work

Can you share the code please?

its gov site for EC download
https://registration.ec.ap.gov.in/ecSearch

@ggorlen
there's no problem with the code; the site itself is not loading via curl, but it has an SSL certificate in the browser.
curl -v https://registration.ec.ap.gov.in/ecSearch/EncumbranceSearch

This page doesn't load for me in the USA

"Failed to connect to registration.ec.ap.gov.in port 443: Connection timed out
" - This shows that the TCP connection to this site failed. A successful TCP connection is requitred before anything involving SSL can even be done, so it does not help to fiddle around with SSL settings, ignoring certificates etc. In other words: there are no SSL related issues here, you are looking at the wrong problem.

@SteffenUllrich can u suggest any solution to buypass this

@ParmeshwarRathod: there is no "bypass" for failing to establish a TCP connection. If there is no "street" to your target then you cannot "bypass" this problem in order to reach your target.
